# aggregate column values to create a new column in python/pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset and I want to create a new column  with the mean of age for the id occurrences and mode for gender  for each id.

```
id  Age  Gender
1   10     F
2    2     M
2   10     F
2   3      F
3   10     M
```

Expected output

```
id Age  Gender
1  10     F
2   5     F
2   5     F
2   5     F
3  10     M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) and apply the [mean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.mean) function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l =[(1,   10   ,  'F')
,(2 ,   2   ,  'M')
,(2 ,  10  ,   'F')
,(2 ,  3  ,    'F')
,(3 ,  10,     'M')]

columns = ['id',  'Age',  'Gender']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

w = Window.partitionBy('id')

df.withColumn('Age', F.mean('Age').over(w)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+------+ 
| id| Age|Gender| 
+---+----+------+ 
|  1|10.0|     F| 
|  3|10.0|     M| 
|  2| 5.0|     F| 
|  2| 5.0|     F| 
|  2| 5.0|     M| 
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: if there are too many columns in dataframe to be aggregated ?

Comment: The number of columns doesn't matter for the calculation of mean.